# Jekyll and Sass sourcemaps

Tags: sass, jekyll

I'm using gulp-ruby-sass to compile my css and generate source maps for a site built on Jekyll. The source maps are being generated. When I inspect a style, a Sass partial is identified as the source of that style. But when I click on the filename, I'm taken to an empty window. I need my entire `scss` directory copied into the `_site` directory when the site is generated. But Jekyll ignores all files prefixed with an underscore, so all Sass partials are automatically excluded. I've tried adding, `scss`, `scss/_sass_partial.scss`, and `scss/**/*.scss` to the `include` property of Jekyll's `_config.yml`. This property is supposed to force inclusion of files that would otherwise be automatically excluded such as `.htaccess`. But this does not work for my Sass partials. Jekyll includes the partials only if the underscore is removed. Does anyone know a way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
include: 
  - _sass_partial.scss
```

But you can also add a gulp task :

```
gulp.task('copy_sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/sass'))
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The only way solution that's worked for me is: `include: ['_scss', '*.scss']` If a filename is included without explicitly including the directory, the filename is ignored. If only the directory is explicitly included, then any underscore prefixed files within the directory are ignored.